# Nested iframes for clickjacking

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I am testing a vulnerable site for clickjacking and here I want to open a link when i click at "check it out" but this link in the frame is not clickable why is that ??? Any solution will be appreciated.

```
 <style>
   iframe 
  { 
   width:500;
   height:500;
   position:absolute;
   top:0; left:0;
        filter:alpha(opacity=50); 

   opacity:0.5;
  }  
 </style>
  <iframe src="http://shop.swatch.com/de_ch/" name="testing"> </iframe> 

 <div> why link is not clickable ? </div>
  <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="testing"> Check it out! </a></p>
```

See This code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhd8cm47/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check new code : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhd8cm47/2/)
You must use `position:absolute` and higher `z-index` property for `Check it out!`

```
   iframe 
  { 
   width:500;
   height:500;
   position:absolute;
   top:0; left:0;
   filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
   opacity:0.5;
   z-index:-1;
  } 
.a{
    z-index:9999;
}

 <iframe src="http://shop.swatch.com/de_ch/" name="testing"> </iframe> 

     <div> why link is not clickable ? </div>
      <p><a class="a" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="testing"> Check it out! </a></p>
```

Comment: Alternatively, he's got the iframe positioned absolutely already, so he could just add `z-index: -1;` to the iframe css, instead of adding it to the link.

Comment: thank's i'm quickly answered and not good think about code! answer edited!